# Friend_array wiping

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a system where a user's friends are stored in an array associated with that user. I have a function that is meant to delete only 1 person from this friend array. However, when this code is triggered from the `remove friend` button it deletes the entire array.  I had the array set up to separate the users by commas (hence the various `$usernameComma` variables)

```
if (@$_POST['removefriend']) {
  //Friend array for logged in user
  $add_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
  $get_friend_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($add_friend_check);
  $friend_array = $get_friend_row['friend_array'];
  $friend_array_explode = explode(",",$friend_array);
  $friend_array_count = count($friend_array_explode);

  //Friend array for user who owns profile
  $add_friend_check_username = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE     username='$username'");
  $get_friend_row_username = mysql_fetch_assoc($add_friend_check_username);
  $friend_array_username = $get_friend_row_username['friend_array'];
  $friend_array_explode_username = explode(",",$friend_array_username);
  $friend_array_count_username = count($friend_array_explode_username);

  $usernameComma = ",".$username;
  $usernameComma2 = $username.",";

  $userComma = ",".$user;
  $userComma2 = $user.",";

  if (strstr($friend_array,$usernameComma)) {
    $friend1 = str_replace("$usernameComma","",$friend_array);
  }
  else
  if (strstr($friend_array,$usernameComma2)) {
   $friend1 = str_replace("$usernameComma2","",$friend_array);
  }
  else
  if (strstr($friend_array,$username)) {
   $friend1 = str_replace("$username","",$friend_array);
  }
  //Remove logged in user from other persons array
  if (strstr($friend_array,$userComma)) {
   $friend2 = str_replace("$userComma","",$friend_array);
  }
  else
  if (strstr($friend_array,$userComma2)) {
   $friend2 = str_replace("$userComma2","",$friend_array);
  }
  else
   if (strstr($friend_array,$user)) {
   $friend2 = str_replace("$user","",$friend_array);
  }

  $friend2 = "";

  $removeFriendQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friend_array='$friend1' WHERE username='$user'");
  $removeFriendQuery_username = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friend_array='$friend2' WHERE username='$username'");
  echo "Friend Removed ...";

}


 ?>
```

Comment: You have a really bad DB schema.  You should not have a string representing the friend relationship in the database, you should have a separate many-to-many join table that expresses this relationship. Until you resolve that problem, you will continue to struggle with this application.

Comment: I had either of these 2 ways to do and I guess I choose wrong.  Is there any way to fix the problem with this version or am a forced to change.

Comment: You could probably fix the problem as is, but I would encourage you to spend that effort on getting your DB set up correctly first.

Comment: With the correct schema (like a `user_friends` table to provide the relationship), there would be no need to update the user table at all, you would just execute a query to delete the row(s) in the join table that express the relationship. I say "row(s)" because oftentimes in a two-way relationship like this, you have a friend relationship between two users expressed as two rows (i.e. `useridA, useridB` in one row, `useridB, useridA` in another) such that you can look up the relationship in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are always wiping out the friend_array for the second user ("other persons array") by setting $friend2 = "" before the queries.

However, definitely go with the suggestion in Mike Brant's comment.  It is a much, much better approach.  It may be more work to change over, but the end result will be much more usable for this and future development.